# Multisite and the JSON REST API: How to?

Tags: plugin-development, multisite, api, rest-api

I have a simple scenario where I have to fetch posts including their metadata from the WordPress REST API: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Within a normal WordPress website this is really simple:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

However I just do not have a clue how to do this in a WordPress Multisite installation. Not one single word about this within the documentation.

I have tried things like:

```
https://www.example.com/blogname/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/blogname
https://www.example.com/blogid/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

But no success so far. ***It is pretty obvious that the JSON REST API is not fully functional and not documented well yet.***

However is there really no easy way to get at least the most important data out of a multisite installation? Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Comment: In my Multisite installation, your first example works: `https://example.com/{sitename}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`, `.../pages`, etc. What kind of Multisite are you running (subdirectory or subdomain)? Try switching to a default theme (`twenty*`) and turning off all plugins.

Comment: @PatJ O.k. thanks. In my sample page it is still not working (the default theme is activated), but I will start with a fresh installation and tell the results here. If it works, I can go for debugging.